# Force.com authenticated site Custom URL

Tags: force.com-sites, authentication

Well this is something supposed to be very easy but doesnt seem to work with Authenticated Sites.

In a force.com Sites we can add custom domains to access the different VF pages. It works fine with UNauthenticated site but once user authenticates to the Site the URL/Domain changes to Force.com domain.

So lets say

- Force.com Site Domain is : **myForce.force.com**
- Custom Domain is : **example.com**
- Force.com site login page : **login.example.com**

So whenever a user is logging in somehow URL changes from **login.example.com** --> **myForce.force.com**

My assumption was it will remain in the custom domain that is configured. I tried to search for information but couldn't find much help. Any Idea if this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, custom domains are not supported for SSL/HTTPS, which means that your authenticated pages will always point to the force.com domain for now. Stay tuned for a future release.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a domain to your Salesforce org (as documented in [Domain Management Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_overview.htm&language=en_US)) you can have your domain point to your Salesforce Site or Community using HTTPS.

- This is considered beta functionality by Salesforce.
- You have to make a support request to start the process.
- It will take a few weeks to be ready to use in your production org.
- You can only test/play/configure this in production.  There will not be a sandbox that will let you play with this functionality successfully.
- If you were using a Community, it can forward/redirect you to the **myforce.force.com** domain if you didn't change some default functionality (the `Network.forwardToAuthPage()` method).

The only way that I see the **login.example.com** authentication page working is if you're using SSO.